# How to clip a MID by a shape using python and gdal/ogr

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, clip

For a project i have to clip point data contain in a mid file with a shape.
Mid file have no header, it's like a text file. Values are separated with comma, and field_2 and field_3 are wgs84 coordinates.
I know that I maybe can do it with gdal/ogr but I'm really lost after reading many documentation.
Somebody can give a way ?